# How to convert String into date format in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a string `201604` and i want the output as `April 2016`

I tried the code below

```
DATEPARSE ("ddMMMyyyy" , [Original Date])
```

but by this I get `1 1 1899`

Comment: To be precise, "April 2016" is not a date. "April 1, 2016" is a date. A date is a compound data type that has 3 components: a month, day and year. You may format the presentation of a date for display and only show the month and year. Or you can extract only one part of the date. If you use DateParse() without providing a day, Tableau will have to assume the day (presumably assuming the first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying for 1.5 hrs i got the answer

```
   DateParse("yyyyMM", [Original Date])
```

or if you want 2016 Sept (1st 3 letters of the month)

```
left(datename('month',DateParse("yyyyMM", [original date])),3)
```

pick up first three alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your Original Date string, you would need to do something like this:

Let's say your Original Date is 03Jan2016, you would need to tell tableau, in a way which it understands, how the format of the current string is, this is done like so:

```
LEFT (First 2 letters), MID(mid3 letters), Right(last 4 letters).

DATE (LEFT([Original Date],2) +
 "/" MID([Original Date],3) + "/" + RIGHT([Original Date],4))
```

Now make this match your current date, and it should be fine.

If it does not understand your current date format, it will give you it's oldest date I guess.

This can also be found in their own KB article here:
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/fixing-date-fields

Comment: i have 201604 it's not (alphabetic)

Answer (score 0):

Dateparse doesn't format a date it *converts* the date into Tableau format. The string specifying the format should specify the format of the date **source** not the date result (which is irrelevant as this will be in tableau's internal date format).

Once converted to a form Tableau can understand, you can format the date any way you want and manipulate the dates using all the built-in functionality that exists in Tableau for manipulating dates.

Despite the fact you have not specified a day in the original date string, doing this correctly as shown below will convert your string into a value of 1 April 2016 which you can format however you want:

```
Dateparse("yyyyMM",[Original Date])
```

Once you have the date in a format Tableau understands, you can use the "Default Format:Date Format" menu (right click the pill for the date variable to get this) and set whatever format you want.